# Jquery slider that slides while mouse move

Tags: jquery, mouse, move, slide

I'm looking for a jquery slider script that is able to right-left slide while I'm moving my mouse. Anyone knows that kind of script? I want to achieve an effect like [this one](http://articles.tutorboy.com/jquery/mouseover-auto-scroller-menu-using-jquery-and-css.html) but it should be scrolled horizontal, not vertical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean something like this. It's a very basic thing that uses the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/). I attach a handler to the mousemove event that just calculates what the value should be for the slider (based on the value of the mouse coordinates).

```
$(function() {

    var range = 100,
        sliderDiv = $("#slider");

    // Activate the UI slider
    sliderDiv.slider({
        min: 0,
        max: range
    });

    // Number of tick marks on slider
    var position = sliderDiv.position(),
        sliderWidth = sliderDiv.width(),
        minX = position.left,
        maxX = minX + sliderWidth,
        tickSize = sliderWidth / range;


    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {

        // If within the slider's width, follow it along
        if (e.pageX >= minX && e.pageX <= maxX) {
            var val = (e.pageX - minX) / tickSize;
            sliderDiv.slider("value", val);
        }

    });

});
```

It's not fantastic code, to be honest, but it does give a basic example of how to use the jQuery UI slider and how to set the value using code.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/qAMWQ/

Comment: no, that's not what I meant, the thing is I want to achieve an effect like this http://articles.tutorboy.com/jquery/mouseover-auto-scroller-menu-using-jquery-and-css.html but it should be scrolled horizontal, not vertical.