# dragging and dropping onto a jquery slider - posting position to server

Tags: html, jquery, user-interface, slider

I'm trying to implement dragging an item onto a jquery slider. For example, if the item is dropped onto 86% of the slider I would like to POST this position to the server so the item can be place 86% along the result set on the server.

How do you detect dropping onto a jQuery slider and the percentage POSTed to the server?

Comment: What do you mean by `item` and `slider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm not so good at explaining things, I made a jsFiddle for you. Although this might not be **exactly** what your looking for, it should be a good starting point!

Here's the code :

```
    $(function () {

    //the draggable object
    $("#dragobject").draggable();

    //Prepare the slider
    var range = 100,
        sliderDiv = $("#slider");

    // Activate the UI slider
    sliderDiv.slider({
        min: 0,
        max: range,
        create : function(){
            $(this).find(".ui-slider-handle").hide();
        }
    });

    // Number of tick marks on slider
    var position = sliderDiv.position(),
        sliderWidth = sliderDiv.width(),
        minX = position.left,
        maxX = minX + sliderWidth,
        tickSize = sliderWidth / range;

    //Set slider as droppable
    sliderDiv.droppable({
        //on drop 
        drop: function (e, ui) {

            var finalMidPosition = $(ui.draggable).position().left + Math.round($("#dragobject").width() / 2);

            //If within the slider's width, follow it along
            if (finalMidPosition >= minX && finalMidPosition <= maxX) {

                var val = Math.round((finalMidPosition - minX) / tickSize);
                sliderDiv.slider("value", val);
                alert(val + "%");

                //do ajax update here to set the position
                /*$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: val,
                    success: function () {
                        //congrats
                    },
                    dataType: dataType
                });*/

            }
        }
    });

});
```

And here's the jsFiddle link : [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BP8hL/4/)

Hope it helps,

Marc.

SOURCES :
[Jquery slider that slides while mouse move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626988/jquery-slider-that-slides-while-mouse-move), 
[jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/)

Comment: That does the trick! Thanks ;-) Do you know if there is a way to stop the handle jumping to the drop point?

Comment: Yes, you could simply doing it using « $(this).find(".ui-slider-handle").hide(); » which target the slider and hide it.

See my updated jsFiddle and answer!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, lets assume you are using jQuery UI for your drag and drop.  First read this: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Then realize that you get the offset position of the dropped element relative to the droppable container as part of the event.  This would be where you could compute that into percentage if you needed.

For example, dropped at position left -> 90px of a container that you know to be 100px wide means 90% is your magic number.

Or if you are using native drag and drop, check out this simple edit: http://jsbin.com/ezuke/3283/edit .  If you pop a console log on the event in the drop event, you will see that it also exposes the offset of where you dropped it and you could again consume that in your calculation of %.